# Rubymine: Cannot read from STDOUT after terminating STDIN

Tags: intellij-idea, eof, rubymine

In Run or Debug mode, I first write input to the console, which is read by STDIN.  I terminate my input with CMD-D (not CTRL-D, see Keyboard Shortcuts https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debug-tool-window-console.html ).  Then attempting to print anything out to STDOUT throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from /path/to/my/script.rb:27:in `<main>'
/path/to/my/script:27:in `p': Input/output error @ io_writev - <STDOUT> (Errno::EIO)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I know you're glued to the screen at this point in fascination with how this story could unfold, so here it comes.  It *works* if you print to STDERR.

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
ins = STDIN.read
puts ins # boom!
```

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
ins = "hi"
puts ins # hi
```

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
ins = STDIN.read
STDERR.puts ins # surprise!  STDERR works.
```

Running RubyMine 2019.1.1 RM-191.6707.59 (Apr 16, 2019) on macOS 10.14.4
ruby-2.6.3 and also tried 2.5.1.

Deep in the debug session, I can see ruby-debug-ide module Debugger has accepted options (in case it means anything to any ruby tools developers):

```
#<OpenStruct frame_bind=false, host="0.0.0.0", load_mode=false, port=53540, stop=false, tracing=false, int_handler=false, dispatcher_port=53541, evaluation_timeout=10, trace_to_s=true, debugger_memory_limit=0, inspect_time_limit=100, rm_protocol_extensions=true, catchpoint_deleted_event=false, value_as_nested_element=false, attach_mode=false, cli_debug=false, key_value_mode=true>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that RubyMine's console doesn't support that, please follow the corresponding request on the RubyMine's tracker:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-24245